# Ограничены или ограниченны?

Tags: орфография

Данные о применении препарата у детей ограничены / ограниченны.

Покопалась в интернете, но все равно не уверена, причастие это или прилагательное.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Данные о применении препарата у детей ограниченны** (незначительны,невелики).

**Это прилагательное**, которое в краткой форме сохраняет две НН.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

**Это тема парных причастий и отпричастных прилагательных** (воспитана – воспитанна, взволнованы – взволнованны и др.).

Существует глагол **ОГРАНИЧИТЬ**: кого-что. 1. Поставить в какие-л. границы, рамки; стеснить какими-л. условиями. О. чью-л. власть.

**От глагола образуется причастие "ограниченный"**: прямое значение, можно подобрать зависимое слово в Т.п. (производитель или инструмент действия).

**Причастие может перейти в прилагательное с качественным значением:** **ОГРАНИЧЕННЫЙ**,  1. **Небольшой, незначительный**. О-ые средства. Соль следует употреблять в ограниченном количестве. О. обзор. О. круг знакомых.  2. **С недостаточными знаниями, с узким кругозором**. Очень о. и самоуверенный человек.

В полной форме **причастие и прилагательное пишутся одинаково**, различать их нет смысла, а в краткой форме мы пишем две НН в прилагательном и одно Н в причастии.

Отсюда следует: Её интересы **ограничены** (чем?) домом и детьми (Т.п.) – это причастие с прямым значением (речь идет о границах).

Ее интересы **ограниченны** (каковы?) – прилагательное (узки, незначительны).

Comment: Почему прилагательное-то?

Comment: Я уже объяснила почему.  Переносное значение, нельзя подобрать слово в Т.п., можно заменить синонимичным прилагательным. Стандартный набор действий для различения причастий и отпричастных прилагательных.

Comment: Это не критерий. Критерий - только значение состояния (причастие) или качества (прилагательное). да и насчет "нельзя подобрать" - сильно сомневаюсь. "Ограничен(н)ы недостатком знаний" (вот не знаю даже, тут причастие или нет). И переносного значения тут тоже нет.

Comment: Переносное значение тут ЕСТЬ: никто для данных "границы не ставил".  Явно качественное значение:  малое количество данных. Если бы это было причастие, то указали бы, чем эти данные ограничены, какие проблемы со сбором данных. Например, данные о применении препарата у детей ограничены  сложностью сбора статистических данных.

Comment: А слово "ограничвать" имеет и другое ***прямое*** значение.  Поставить в какие-л. границы, рамки; ***стеснить какими-л. условиями***. (БТС Кузнецова).

Answer (score 3):

> Данные о применении препарата у детей ограничены / ограниченны.

Здесь правильно —  ***ограниченны.***

См. *[**Орфографический словарь:**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)*

> ***ограниченный***; кр. ф. прич. ***-ен, -ена;*** кр. ф. прил. ***-ен, -ена*** (с дополн.: *её интересы ограничены домом и детьми*) и ***-ен, -енна*** (**без
>   дополн.:** *наши возможности **ограниченны;** она самоуверенна и
>   **ограниченна***)

Comment: Интересно, почему в *Её интересы ограничены домом и детьми* "ограничены" — краткое прилагательное.


Помнится, на Грамме была статья с примерами: *Девушка воспитана бабушкой* - кр.прич. *Девушка умна и воспитанна* - кр.прил.

Comment: @ Niemand Да всё правильно с позиций школьной науки. Нет зависимых слов - прилагательное, есть - причастие. Но это только школьный подход.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь вообще-то от смысла зависит. 
Если речь идет о недостаточности данных, то "ограниченны" - значение признака, то есть вероятное прилагательное.
Если данные кто-то засекретил (а вдруг?) то возможно и ограничены - значение действия, причастия. Хотя прилагательное тоже возможно.

Здесь скорее всего первый случай (поэтому словарь столь категоричен), но если даже второй, то написание с двумя Н не будет ошибкой.