# Краткое причастие/прилагательное (н/нн)?

Tags: причастия

Предложение:
Основная проблема экономики: потребности безграничны, а доступные ресурсы ограничены/ ограниченны.

Нет зависимого слова, но не совсем нравится замена прилагательным (небольшие (?)).

Подобный вопрос был, но на всякий случай уточняю (ссылка на подобный вопрос): [Ограничены или ограниченны?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432438/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная проблема экономики: потребности безграничны, **а доступные ресурсы (каковы?) ограниченны (=невелики).**

Это не причастие, а краткое прилагательное (две буквы НН).

Здесь **нет значения действия** (доступные ресурсы никто не ограничивал), просто этих ресурсов пока еще мало.