# Как правильно написать ограниченно/ограничено и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

1. Предложение ограниченно и действует, пока товар есть в наличии.
2. Предложение ограничено и действует пока товар есть в наличии.
3. Предложение ограничено и действует, пока товар есть в наличии.
4. Предложение ограниченно и действует, пока товар есть в наличии.

Comment: https://mel.fm/gramotnost/kak-pisat/7453902-kolichestvo-mest-v-zale-ogranichenno-ili-ogranicheno-kak-pisat-pravilno#:~:text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE,%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%C2%AB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%C2%BB.

Answer (score 2):

Если **ограничено** - причастие, то одна н, если прилагательное - то две н, если наречие, то в данном случае две:

```
Предложение ограничено доступным товаром.
Предложение действует ограниченно.
Предложение ограничено и действует, пока товар есть в наличии.
Предложение ограниченно и глупо.
```

https://rg.ru/2016/02/25/kak-pisat-pravilno-ogranicheno-ili-ogranichenno.html

Comment: Интересная ссылка, но я не уверена, что друзья правы, а корректор неправ))

Comment: @Sharon,мне кажется, что в словаре говорится о причастии при дополнении. Ее интересы ограничены домом и детьми.

Comment: Серж, в словаре РАН сначала названо краткое ПРИЧАСТИЕ, и это понятно, например: площадь ограничена кругом. Потом идет краткое ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ с переносным значением, причем рассматриваются два варианта (с дополнением и без дополнения). Рассмотрим: Ее интересы ограничены домом и детьми. Значение не прямое, а переносное (дом и дети не могут ограничить интересы, как круг.)  По словарю РАН  в кратком прилагательном  при наличии дополнения пишется Н.

Comment: @Sharon, тогда что получается: при наличии дополнения у нас и краткое прилагательное и краткое причастие?

Comment: Я думаю, что на дополнение мы ориентируемся только при переносном значении, что характерно для ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ. (Это обычный принцип  во многих случаях.) Но для этой группы прилагательных действует  еще и ОСОБОЕ правило –  выбор по дополнению. Поэтому надо обязательно смотреть в словарь РАН.  Что касается ПРИЧАСТИЙ, то у них прямое значение (признак по действию). Сравнить: Эти горы образованы уже давно. Здесь нет дополнения,  но это причастие. Урок ограничен по времени.  Это тоже причастие. Площадь ограничена кругом. А здесь уже причастие с дополнением.

Comment: Таким образом, сначала ориентируемся на ПЕРЕНОСНОЕ или ПРЯМОЕ значение для ограничено/ограниченно, а уже потом на все остальное. Это правило РАН, и нарушать его нежелательно, хотя споры ведутся и многим КАЖЕТСЯ, что это не так. (Мы это видим и по ссылке. ) Но я участвовать в этих боях и что-либо доказывать не буду. Можно приводить примеры из практики письма, но и там надо сначала увидеть прямое или переносное значение, а потом уже делать вывод. Я не хотела отвечать на вопрос, зная ситуацию, а ответила только потому, что НЕ БЫЛО других однозначных  ответов

Comment: Но в этом ответе вы утверждаете, что это причастие. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432438/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b

Comment: И вообще странно. С каких пор прилагательное с зависимым словом в творительном падеже является кратким прилагательном?

Comment: Тут вот еще интересный момент. Предложение ограничено и действует... Это однородные сказуемые? Что-то непохоже.  Предложение (каково?)  в ограниченных пределах и действует... Это уже лучше. Два последовательных сообщения:  сначала указана ограниченность предложение, а затем объясняется причина ограниченности.

Comment: Серж, ваши вопросы скорее к РАН, а не ко мне. А в моем ответе 2017 года, вероятно,  еще не учтена  корректирующая информация РАН. Что касается моих взглядов сегодня,  то в этой теме нужно иметь очень тонкое языковое чутье, чтобы различить прямое и переносное значения. А где же его взять-то, если мы привыкли формальными правилами пользоваться. Вот пользователи и спорят, сами видите))

Comment: @Sharon, интересный ответ Грамоты.ру. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B&start=15

Comment: Да, Серж, ответ интересный. КАРТИНКА ТАКАЯ: корректоры пытаются противостоять некорректным действиям со стороны пользователей. Самые нестойкие (корректоры) сдаются, их дожимают  многочисленные "друзья". Но вспомним Высоцкого: "Их восемь — нас двое. Расклад перед боем Не наш, но мы будем играть!"

Comment: @Sharon, см.ответ РАН.

Answer (score 1):

Я выберу первый вариант. Поддержу корректора из ссылки; возможно, на него оказали силовое воздействие))

*Предложение **ограниченно** и действует, пока товар есть в наличии.*

**Пояснение**

1. Существует прилагательное «ограниченный» согласно словарю.

**ОГРАНИЧЕННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -чен, -ченна, -ченно. 1. Небольшой, незначительный. О-ые средства. Соль следует употреблять в ограниченном количестве. О. обзор. О. круг знакомых. Человек ограниченных способностей.

2. Фразу можно записать так:  *Предложение **в ограниченных пределах** (ограниченно) и действует, пока товар есть в наличии.*
3. При решении ориентируемся **на словарь РАН** (дополнения у нас нет):

**ОГРАНИЧЕННЫЙ**;  кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; **кр. ф. прил.** -ен, -ена (с дополн.: её интересы ограничены домом и детьми) и **-ен, -енна** (без дополн.: **наши возможности ограниченны**; она самоуверенна и ограниченна)

4. **Запятая** ставится в СПП с придаточным времени перед союзом ПОКА.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146988/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Это значение в словарях отдано причастию, у прилагательного его нет. Это отражает традицию употребления этого слова (причастие и прилагательное разошлись по значению). Поэтому так не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же, нужно употребить форму причастия: "предложение ограниче**н**о". За скобки вынесено [по времени], то есть маркетологи ограничили действие этого предложения определенным временным промежутком.

> прич.; кр.ф. ограни/чен, ограни/чена, -чено, -чены.
> ***Количество посетителей к этому больному ограничено врачами.***

---

И так могло длиться до бесконечности, если бы наше пребывание в Тбилиси не было **ограничено** по времени. [Борис Мессерер. Промельк Беллы. Главы из книги // «Октябрь», 2013]
[Галина Солоденкова (жен)]

---

Помним, что время **ограничено**, а тематика вопросов повторяется, немного усложняясь каждый раз, по мере продвижения к заветной цифре 40. [Форум: Тест на IQ это интересно. Хоть поверьте, хоть проверьте (2013)]

Comment: Да, здесь нужна форма причастия, но "по времени" может употребляться и с прилагательными (*длинный по времени, точный по времени*), поэтому не из-за этого.

Comment: @oleedd наличие глагольного актуализатора доказывает причастность, тут вы не правы.

Comment: "По времени" не актуализирует глагольность, оно способствует качеству ("какой по времени?", а не "что сделанный по времени?"). Превращают в причастия те зависимые слова, которые не могут употребляться с прилагательными.

Comment: @oleedd это ваши домыслы. Глагольные актуализаторы -- это как раз те части высказывания, которые подчеркивают глагольность слова, средства, выявляющие («актуализирующие») глагольное значение: указания на время действия, место, способ, агент действия.

Comment: Здесь нет актуализации. Это ваши домыслы. Даже в вопрос прилагательного эти зависимые слова добавляются: *какой по времени?* Ничего здесь не актуализируется. Далеко не все зависимые слова превращают в причастия. Почитайте эту тему у Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80 Там есть примеры с прилагательными и зависимыми словами.

Comment: Сравните с реальными актуализаторами: *ограниченное вчера предложение* — "какое вчера?" не подходит; *ограниченное компанией предложение* — "какое компанией?" неверно.

Comment: И там не "по времени", а о количестве товара (во второй половине поясняется ограничение).

Comment: @oleedd И что вы скинули? Речь там шла о переносных значениях. Данный вопрос касается разграничения причастия и отглагольного прилагательного: наличие зависимого слова актуализует глагольность слова. Вы не понимаете, о чем говорите. Понятное дело, что некоторые прилагательные могут иметь зависимые слова, тем более тогда, когда появляется новое слово благодаря "не", однако это никакого отношения к данной теме не имеет. Основной признак причастия - возможность иметь при себе зависимое слово, что демонстрирует причастность.

Comment: Ну это не актуализирует. Ответ ваш, вам надо оправдываться и доказывать. Ну вы это не докажете, потому что здесь 100% так, это просто ясно, как пень. Когда актуализация, вопрос "какой?" не подходит, а здесь подходит. Не все зависимые слова актуализируют. Вы ещё скажите, что в "очень обиженный" "очень" актуализирует. Поправка: возможность иметь при себе зависимое слово, которое не могут иметь прилагательные из-за отсутствия глагольности.

Comment: @oleedd Это ваши домыслы. Время, условие, причина, объект - все это актуализирует глагольность. Больше не отвечу вам.

Comment: Ваш ответ неверный. Здесь нет ни времени, ни условия, ни причины, ни объекта. Некоторые зависимые слова способствуют глагольности, а некоторые качеству. Это базовая вещь. Странно, что учитель этого не знает. Стыдно. Вы настолько самоуверенны, что считаете себя умнее выдающихся лингвистов, хотя вы никто в сравнении с ними.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу Ajgy** (мое мнение, не для обсуждения)

В заданном варианте предложение ограничено **наличием товара**, а не временем, но эта причина обозначена **во второй части** сообщения, а в первой части мы этого не знаем. Ведь ограничение возможно **по разным мотивам.**

Поэтому в первой части мы используем **краткое прилагательное** "ограниченно". Сравнить:  *Предложение ограниченно. Предложение ограничено наличием товара.* Это  краткие прилагательные (две формы письма) с **переносным** значением.

А это уже **причастия (прямое значение):** *Время ограничено*. Имеется в виду конкретная величина, например не больше 10 минут. *Пребывание ограничено по времени* (три дня). *Количество посетителей **ограничено** врачами* (не более трех человек). В то же время можно написать: *количество посетителей **ограниченно*** (толпу не пускать). Тогда это будет прилагательное.

Значение **причастия** (признак по действию) **не зависит от синтаксиса** предложения (от наличия дополнения и др.), а определяется **по смыслу** с учетом разных смысловых факторов (в отличие от прилагательного, где форму письма определяет дополнение).

И еще просьба обратить внимание **на [ответ Грамоты.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B&start=15)**.

**Вопрос № 229683**
Спасибо за ответ. Об этом критерии – наличии дополнения – я читала в ваших ответах и раньше. Экономически – это не дополнение, правильно? Обязательно ли, чтобы дополнение было выражено существительным в творительном падеже (**Ее интересы ограничены домом и детьми**)? Не раз читала ваши разъяснения насчет **написания н и нн в слове огрниченны**, но продолжает смущать тот факт, что ВСЕ пишут везде с одним н. **Я как редактор старательно исправляю эту ошибку** (под влиянием ваших разъяснений), но червячок сомнений остается. *Количество мест ограниченно, количество автомобилей ограниченно, количество предложений ограниченно, движение по этой улице ограниченно* – **это всё один и тот же случай**? Хотелось бы услышать ОКОНЧАТЕЛЬНЫЙ ответ, чтобы сомнения отпали.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка.**  Экономически – это не дополнение. Дополнением, влияющим на написание *н* и *нн,* является имя или местоимение в творительном падеже. **В приведенных Вами примерах пишется *нн.***

Я думаю, что в этих примерах **переносное** значение прилагательных, то есть не конкретная величина, а неопределенная (ограниченное количество). Поэтому решение дается по правилу РАН для прилагательных. Но пользователи считают, что это причастие с **прямым** значением. Как раз в этом и состоит **причина** "конфликта". Ситуация просто **тупиковая**))

Надо сказать, что иногда разница между прямым значением причастия и переносным значением прилагательного ощущается явно, но не всегда (например, в данном случае). И если есть **сомнения**, то нужно обязательно смотреть **в словарь РАН**.

Словарь – это не правила письма, где возможно авторское решение. И не ответы Грамоты.ру, где не все бывает безусловно верным. Рекомендации орфографического словаря **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫ** для исполнения, это как бы закон, который нельзя нарушать.

Comment: Это ваше мнение, однако я с ним категорически не согласен. Возьмите тот же словарь РАН, однако не бумажную версию, а электронную, которая обновляется каждый год. Для слова "ограниченный" указано лишь одно значение с "нн": ограни́ченный; кр. ф. прич. и прил. -ен, -ена (они́ ограни́чены в сре́дствах; ограни́чены территориа́льно; интере́сы ограни́чены рабо́той; коли́чество това́ров ограни́чено; на́ши возмо́жности ограни́чены); кр. ф. прил. (недостаточно развитый) -ен, -енна (она́ самоуве́ренна и ограни́ченна).

Comment: Я использую именно электронную версию на Грамоте.ру.  Вся информация по словарям  взята  оттуда, и я ее просто комментирую, вот и все мое мнение. Можно не соглашаться с этим мнением, но посмотрите, как много информации на  тему этих слов в Интернете, и я не уверена, что ваша точка зрения является самой правильной. В любом случае в нашей задаче я считаю верным форму прилагательного "ограниченно", а вы выбираете форму «ограничено».  Каждый из нас доказывает свое понимание, но давайте будем сравнивать именно само решение. Зачем нам категорически не соглашаться с кем-то, лучше уж доказывать свое))

Comment: Я тоже ее использую, но не только. Всегда смотрю разные словари: Словарь трудностей под авторством Еськовой, Орфографический словарь 2006 года, электронную версию современного орфографического слова на сайте "Академос", к МАСу также обращаюсь при необходимости. Сравнивать всегда нужно! Что же касается правописания "н" и "нн" в отглагольных прилагательных и причастиях, всё не так однозначно. Официально принятых новых правил на этот счет нет. Если только рекомендации современных словарей, в том числе Орфографического словаря. Недавно специально уточнял этот вопрос у специалистов ...

Comment: "Грамоты", они ответили, что вполне себе можно апеллировать и к ранее изданным словарям, и это не может быть не учтено. Как мне сказали, данная тема вынесена на обсуждение орфографической комиссии, и в скором времени планируется найти четкие критерии разграничения этих форм. Возможно, имеющееся в языке правило будет скорректировано, что позволит снять большинство вопросов к этому разделу. Пока что это лишь разговоры. Из-за того, что такого правила пока нет, на письме мы можем увидеть отличающиеся друг от друга варианты, так как при анализе конкретного примера  люди обращаются к разным словарям

Comment: Я не приветствую однозначную правильность, которую собирается предложить нам комиссия. В частности эта тема имеет смысловое решение, а не формальное. И не факт, что все интеллектуальное сообщество будет строиться перед новой орфографической комиссией - много ли там будет академиков, как в 1956 году. У них у самих много разногласий. А вот новый орфографический словарь – это не правила, и надо следовать ему как гаранту хотя какой-то стабильности. А жить по старым словарям и учебникам мне как-то не хочется.

Comment: Там все академики, академия наук же. И "по времени" в причастие не превращает, оно без проблем употребляется с прилагательными (*короткий по времени, длинный по времени*). Эти примеры показывают, что слова с "по" не влияют: *Она ограниченна по знаниям. Она ограниченна по способностям.*

Answer (score 1):

Критерии разграничения причастий и отглагольных прилагательных — одна из актуальных проблем современной русистики: лингвисты признают, что во многих контекстах невозможно строго различить причастие и прилагательное. Так, в статье С. С. Сая «Причастие», опубликованной на сайте «Русская корпусная грамматика» (ссылка на страницу: http://rusgram.ru/) говорится: «Провести четкую границу между «еще причастиями» и «уже прилагательными», переставшими быть словоформами глаголов, принципиально невозможно. Способность к адъективации — это неотъемлемое свойство, заложенное в самой природе русских причастий; практически любое русское причастие в той или иной степени способно его демонстрировать» [см. статья «Причастие», § 5.2.2].

Разумеется, сложности с разграничением причастий и прилагательных неминуемо приводят к сложностям в их правописании. Составители орфографических словарей и справочников по правописанию по сей день пытаются решить эту проблему. Прежде (например, в «Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 г.) правило написания н или нн в кратких формах отглагольных прилагательных / причастий прошедшего времени строилось на следующем противопоставлении: в кратких причастиях пишется только н, в кратких отглагольных прилагательных — только нн. Однако, как отмечают специалисты, такое правило сложно в применении, к тому же оно не учитывало реальной практики письма. По этой причине специалисты в области орфографии приняли решение допустить написание н в кратких отглагольных прилагательных (иными словами, в некоторых кратких отглагольных прилагательных теперь допустимо написание как нн, так и н; напомним, Правилами 1956 г. такое написание предусмотрено не было). Так, в полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина 2006 г. (электронная версия справочника доступна в сети Интернет на странице с адресом: https://orfogrammka.ru/) допускается написание одной буквы н в кратких прилагательных [см. общее правило и подробное примечание в § 102].

Рекомендация относительно правописания интересующего Вас слова ограниченный, содержащаяся в «Русском орфографическом словаре» под ред. В. В. Лопатина, продиктована необходимостью учесть, с одной стороны, семантику слова ограниченный (ведь, как Вы совершенно справедливо отметили, в примере её интересы ограничены домом и детьми слово ограничены использовано в значении, свойственном прилагательному, а не причастию), с другой стороны, грамматическую сочетаемость этого прилагательного (не причастия!). Пример её интересы ограничены домом и детьми демонстрирует, что краткая форма прилагательного ограниченный может употребляться в, на первый взгляд, типичной для причастия позиции — с зависимым словом в творительном падеже — и писаться с одной н, но являться при этом прилагательным, не переходить в разряд причастий (первостепенную роль в данном случае играет семантика слова). Аналогично (при зависимом слове в творительном падеже, но с одной н) пишется, например, краткая форма прилагательного оправданный (ср.: оправданный, но: затраты оправданы важностью проекта).

В заключение можем порекомендовать Вам орфографический академический ресурс «Академос» (ссылка на страницу: https://orfo.ruslang.ru/), имеющий статус официальной публикации Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН. В настоящее время это, безусловно, наиболее авторитетный источник орфографической нормы, живо реагирующий на те или иные изменения в русском языке. Искренне надеемся, что ресурс будет полезен для Вас.

**С уважением**

**Евгений Базаров, сотрудник отдела культуры русской речи ИРЯ РАН**